# How to query from a many-to-many to select specific items from a db table in template django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to use my many-to-many table to reference which majors I want to display on my website page

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    school_Major_merge = models.ManyToManyField(Major, through='School_Major')

class School_Major(models.Model):
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class professor(models.Model):
    ProfessorIDS = models.IntegerField()
    ProfessorName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ProfessorRating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    NumberofRatings = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #delete major from the model  
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfessorName
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import professor, School , School_Major, Major


def index(request):
    # professors = professor.objects.all()
    # return render(request, 'locate/index.html', {'professors': professors})
    schools = School.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'locate/index.html', {'schools': schools})


def Major(request, Major):
    major_choice = professor.objects.filter(Major =Major)
    return render(request, 'locate/major.html', {'major_choice': major_choice})
```

**url.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:Major>/', views.Major, name='Major')
]
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to write out my views where When selecting a specific school, I would be able to use the School_Major to reference specifically what majors to display on my major section of my site,

on my index.html I have the following for-loop

```
  <ul>
    {% for list in schools %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'view' '{{list.id}}' %}">{{list.name}}</a></li>
    <br><br>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

The **'view'** being a function which would take in the School PK and use the School_Major table to reference which Majors are available to that School, and display the Majors

I will have example pictures of each table for more visualization.

**School**

[image]

**School Major**
[image]

**Major**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont Know why you created School_Major Model.

to acess M2M .
add a function below your model

```
def get_yourfunctionname(self):
    return ", ".join([x.field_you_want for x in self.your_M2M_Field_name.all()])
```

In Template

```
    <ul>
    {% for list in schools %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'view' '{{list.id}}' %}">{{list.get_yourfunctionname}}</a></li>
    <br><br>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

Comment: The reason I added the School_Major model was because I had data inside in a excel file, and a populating script that only works by looking for model classes, so I had to make an independent class to represent the m2m association. and did you mean within my School Class?